# Why getting access denied when starting a port

Tags: linux, socket-activation

I have a RHEL 8 Linux and using db2 when starting a services of db2 (`hadr`) we get in the diag an error message like below. The command to start the `hadr` service does not return an error but the remote machine can not connect to this port either. The FW and SELinux have been disabled. The system person does not have an idea about it. Any help is welcome.

```
2023-12-15-08.07.33.324997+060 E46646E616 LEVEL: Error (OS) 
PID : 10565 TID : 140583339288320 PROC : db2sysc 0 
INSTANCE: dbadma NODE : 000 DB : ACC1 
HOSTNAME: uhdb2accdr.uhasselt.be 
EDUID : 95 EDUNAME: db2hadrs.0.0 (ACC1) 0 
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, oper system services, sqloPdbQuerySocketErrorStatus, probe:15 
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x840F0001=-2079391743=SQLO_ACCD "Access Denied" DIA8701C Access denied for resource "", operating system return code was "". 
CALLED : OS, -, getsockopt OSERR: EACCES (13)
```

A suggestion was to strace the startup, but this start command ends successfully but calls a background/asynch process to listen on the port. The strace ends when the start command returns the shell command line.

Thanks for all help/info
Best regards, Guy

Comment: run it as root?

Comment: Not possible.  Must be started as db2 instance owner

Comment: The issue seems to be related to this one here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/dia8701c-access-denied-message-issued-kuddb2

Comment: thks for update - but this is not a client but server - the  message is access denied for a socket - not a file - the socket has been created and  present but can not be used from remote process trying to connect to this machine